# F#, Akka.net - Nunit3 not running tests when inheriting from TestkKit

Tags: inheritance, f#, akka.net, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to run tests with NUnit 3 from some F# code.

I'm creating a class that inherits from the Akka.Net TestKit class like is standard practice in the C# paradigm.

When I run the tests from Visual studio (and from the nunit3-console.exe) executable it fails to find the tests. It finds the tests when it doesn't inherit from the TestKit class.

```
open NUnit.Framework
open Akka.TestKit

[<TestFixture>]
type SomeActorTests() = 
    inherit Akka.TestKit.NUnit3.TestKit()
    [<Test>]
    member self.TestThatSomeStuffIsTrue() = 
        Assert.True true
```

Anyone know why this could be? I'm fairly new to F# and don't know why inheriting from a base class would cause the TestFixture attribute to be ignored.

The code compiles and I have these as packages:

```
<package id="Akka" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Akka.TestKit" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Akka.TestKit.NUnit3" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="NUnit" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.1.36" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the **Visual Studio test runner**:

It seems as though the Akka test kit **does not yet work with NUnit 3.0** (see this thread: https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.TestKit.Nunit/issues/10)

To work around this, you could downgrade NUnit to 2.x. Another option would be to switch frameworks and use https://github.com/akkadotnet/Akka.TestKit.VsTest (a big pain, I know).

Alternatively, if you have the option to use the **ReSharper Test Runner**, that partially works. If you install this, note it is not yet compatible with NUnit 3.4.1, so use **3.0.0** (nothing later works).

Lastly, I have found that using the **NCrunch test runner** works with all versions of NUnit.

Comment: Downgrading NUnit works. Not sure why I didn't try it in the first place. Cheers!